# Is it good practice to use multiple form elements for different actions?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

I'm wondering if you can have a HTML form with multiple actions. Well, I don't mean specifying more than one `action=""` attribute. Say I have a simple form:

**form.html**

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
  <label><input type="radio" value="r1" id="r1" name="r" />Insert in table1</label><br/>
  <label><input type="radio" value="r2" id="r2" name="r" />Insert in table2</label><br/>
  <label>Value 1<input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" /></label><br/>
  <label>Value 2<input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" /></label><br/>
  <label><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></label><br/>
</form>
```

**action.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("example.com","user","pwd","db");
$r = $_POST["r"];
$t1 = $_POST["t1"];
$t2 = $_POST["t2"];
switch($r):
  case 'r1':
    if($q = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?, ?)")):
      $q -> bind_param("ss",$t1,$t2);
      if($q -> execute()):
        echo 'Successfully updated table1.';
        $q -> close();
      endif;
    endif;
    break;
  case 'r2':
    if($q = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (?, ?)")):
      $q -> bind_param("ss",$t1,$t2);
      if($q -> execute()):
        echo 'Successfully updated table2.';
        $q -> close();
      endif;
    endif;
    break;
endswitch;
mysqli_close($con);
```

So I update either `table1` or `table2` based on the radio input, with the user submitted values. Notice that I have prevented SQL Injection. So my question is, is this good practice, or I should make two forms each having a different `action=""`(switching between them using a `query string`, say `/main.php?form=form1` or `/main.php?form=form2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is fine. Another way to do it is with multiple `Submit` buttons. The submit buttons can use the `formaction` attribute to specify a different URL:

```
<input type="submit" formaction="main.php?action=form1" value="Insert in table1"/>
<input type="submit" formaction="main.php?action=form2" value="Insert in table2"/>
```

`formaction` overrides the form's `action` attribute when you click on that submit button.

Then you can use `switch($_GET['action'])` in the PHP.

Comment: What if an user presses the enter key to submit? Which `input` will be "pressed"?

Comment: The name/value of the first submit button is sent to the server, but I'm not sure if this means it uses the first button's `formaction` URL as well.

Comment: Gotta check it out, I'll be back with an answer, if nobody else is gonna be faster.  EDIT: Well, that was quite fast. Yes, if an user presses the enter key, then the it will act like the first `input` was pressed, meaning it will use the its `formaction` and `name`/`value`.

Answer (score -1):

One form is fine (and, in most cases, easier and more consistent<sup>2</sup>). The code can do whatever is required depending on the data/state: the fact that this case involves a different table in each action is irrelevant<sup>1</sup>

Since a radio-button is used as the discriminator, it actually *must* be the same form (and thus same action) without wonky client-side JavaScript mangling - this is because the radio button itself can participate in exactly one form.

---

<sup>1</sup> To see the the actions performed really don't matter, consider if the code was written as the following, where the actions themselves are a "black box".

```
case 'r1': f1(); break;
case 'r2': f2(); break;
```

<sup>2</sup> There are some arguments to be made for separate forms/actions, especially when trying to adhere to REST or POST/GET differences and idempotent behavior rules; but this cannot be argued with merely the above (or the example in the post). I'll not defend or condone the presented interface.

Comment: (If you do downvote, please leave an explanation why - this will allow me to fix/amend or defend the positions, or retract the answer entirely. Otherwise, I have no idea what is "wrong".)

Comment: Downvoters should comment indeed, I found this answer quite helpful.